# Howto setup multiple TLDs for multisite in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I tried nearly everything for now 2 days but i can´t figure out what is the problem.

we have three websites, which all now get a small shop. so we decided to use wordpress and woocommerce. We also decided to use multisite for easier management.

The sites shall run on 3 different TLD as subsite.

No matter what i do, no matter which link i follow and which tutorials i follow, i can´t get it to run. The domains are all assigned as subdomains, new.site1.com, new.site2.com and new.site3.com and also point correctly to the directory.

But i can´t login to a subsite, execpting the main site. Everytime i want to switch to a subsite which is not the main site, i will get redirected back. This also happens in the frontend.

It also doesn't matter if the installation is clean or not. I also tried it out with no plugins activated. Like already said, i followed every guide.

The domains are btw. "just" domain alias defined in plesk. Maybe that is a problem for wordpress? Is that possible? If yes, i need to tell my boss "buy new domains".

I wonder if there is someone out there who has the same problem like me right now.

The next step would be to use 3 instances again, but that´s not really what i want. So i hope anyone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean new1.site.com, new2.site.com, new3.site.com?

Comment: not really, no. i meant i have 3 different TLDs. the "new" is just because i just have these domains for testing. later it will have site1.com, site2.com and site3.com again